# complex integral over a dislocated circle

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

We are working on the complex plane here.
I can't solve what seems to be a quite easy integral.

\begin{equation}
\int_{|z-1|=1}\frac{1}{z^2-1}dz
\end{equation}

I would use the Barrow rule, but unfortunately, there are discontinuity points, so I am not sure you can just use the primitive of the function.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you know what the residue theorem is?

Comment: You could solve the integral explicitly by parameterising, or as @spinosarus123 has mentioned residue theorem yields the answer very quickly. Or even use Cauchy's integral formula

Comment: Thank you with the suggestions, I'll go with the Cauchy's formula

Answer (score 3):

Write $$\frac{1}{z^2 - 1} = \frac{f(z)}{z-1}$$ where $f(z) = \frac{1}{z+1}$. Since $f$ is analytic inside and on the curve $|z - 1| = 1$, the Cauchy integral formula yields the result $2\pi i f(1) = \pi i$.